# Decrease Protractor/Jasmine test delay between it()

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I wanted to know if there is a way to decrease the delay between each it() function. It looks like the default is around 3 seconds.

Comment: There is no additional delay for me. I've never seen 3 seconds delay between it(), not even 1 second.

Comment: Same here. Please provide the configuration you have and a sample set of tests so we can reproduce the issue. Otherwise, it is "too broad".

Comment: By reading your comments, I found my mistake. I had in my beforeEach() a page reload. I took it off and it was quick enough for me. Thanks guys!